# Iteratively removing final part of strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset with a column of long strings that serve as IDs, constructed in sections that are separated by numbers. For example:

```
"_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"
"_1_woman_2_highincome_3_notCA_4_unmarried"
"_1_man_2_lowincome_3_CA_4_unmarried"
```

and so on.

I need to shorten these IDs by removing the last section until each ID type has at least 4 observations. So if there are only 3 observations with the ID "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married", I need to remove the final section "_4_married" from all occurrences of that string.

It was fairly simple to write a function "identify_IDs_to_merge.R" that outputs a table "IDs_to_merge" of the ID types that have fewer than 4 observations as well as "num_IDs_to_merge". I also have the variable "num_tags" with the number of sections in the strings. I'm struggling to write a while loop that will actually alter the IDs, though. Here is my effort so far:

```
source("identify_IDs_to_merge.R")

lowest_tag <- num_tags

while (num_IDs_to_merge > 0){
  # strip last tag
  pattern_to_strip <- paste('_', as.character(lowest_tag), '_.*', sep = '')
  data$id[data$id %in% IDs_to_merge$id] <-
gsub(pattern_to_strip, "", data$id[data$id %in% IDs_to_merge$id])

  # reassign lowest tag
  lowest_tag <- lowest_tag - 1

  # identify and count remaining IDs with < 4 observations
  source("identify_IDs_to_merge.R")
}
```

The code is just crashing, though, and I know it must be a problem with my while loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some more example input along with expected output ?

Comment: `"_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married" %>% strsplit("_") %>% unlist() %>% .[1:7] %>% glue::glue_collapse("_")`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = c("_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married",
      "_1_woman_2_highincome_3_notCA_4_unmarried",
      "_1_man_2_lowincome_3_CA_4_unmarried")

#add one case with 4 occurences
a=c(a,rep(a[1],3))

a
[1] "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"        "_1_woman_2_highincome_3_notCA_4_unmarried"
[3] "_1_man_2_lowincome_3_CA_4_unmarried"       "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"       
[5] "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"        "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"

#find all ID with more than 3 occurences
hits = a[match(names(table(a))[table(a)>3],a)]

#perform subtraction for releveant IDs
for (i in 1:length(hits)){
  a[match(hits[i],a)]<-gsub("_4_married","",a[match(hits[i],a)])
  }

a

[1] "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA"                  "_1_woman_2_highincome_3_notCA_4_unmarried"
[3] "_1_man_2_lowincome_3_CA_4_unmarried"       "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"       
[5] "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"        "_1_man_2_highincome_3_CA_4_married"
```

Maybe this helps?